# Getting error Invalid type for parameter, value: ['db/', 'db1/'], type: <class 'list'>, valid types: <class 'str'> while reading folders in S3 buckets

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3, botocore

I need to list subfolders of some specific folders in my S3 Bucket ('db', 'db1', 'db2')
I'm setting an array with the folders of interest, and not all of them inside the bucket.
I'm using this 'filter Prefix' method, but it doesn't accept array.

```
import boto
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3.Bucket('database_buckets')
for object_summary in my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=["db/", "db1/", "db2/"]):
    print(object_summary.key)
```

**Error: botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter Prefix, value: ['db/', 'db1/', 'db2/'], type: <class 'list'>, valid types: <class 'str'>**

Any ideas for me to list these files inside these specific folders?
As there are many folders (more than 30), it would be ideal to do with array.

Comment: from boto3 documentation: "Prefix (string) -- Limits the response to keys that begin with the specified prefix."

Comment: call `filter()` for each prefix it will work

Comment: Thanks @deadshot.
I can do it this way, but as there are many folders, I'm still looking for other ways.

Comment: no, it's not possible you can't pass multiple prefixes in single filter call